# chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible= msoFalse getting mismatch error

Tags: ms-access

I have created a object and need to set Format.Glow, Format.Fill and Format.SoftEdge.Radius etc

The code from excel uses With Selection but that's not allowed in access.  I used the watch window and see the properties but can't assign anything.

enter code here

```
For Each chtobj In shtTemp.ChartObjects
If chtobj.Name = "Chart4" Then
    Debug.Print chtobj.Name
    '
    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Transparency = 0
    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Solid

    With chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Glow
            .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Radius = 10
    End With

    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    chtobj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.SoftEdge.Radius = 1

End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct syntax for VBA:

```
chtobj.Chart.Shapes.Parent.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
```